# Garble that string!

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

Given a string as input, output one or more variants of the string such that:

- No character is in it's original position
- No character is adjacent to a character that it was originally adjacent to

You can assume this will always be possible for the given string, and will only contain single case alphabetical characters (`[a-z]` or `[A-Z]` if you prefer)

Note that duplicates of the same character are not considered unique.

For example, given the input `programming`, the output cannot contain an `m` at the 7th **or** 8th character, and cannot contain a `g` at the 4th **or** 11th character (1 indexed)

### Example:

Take the string `abcdef`

The following would be a valid output: `daecfb`

However the following would be invalid: `fdbcae` as in this example `c` and `b` are still adjacent.

Adjacency also wraps, meaning you could not do `fdbeca` as `f` and `a` are still adjacent.

### Testcases:

Note these are not the **only** valid outputs for the given inputs

Written as `input -> output`:

```
helowi -> ioewhl
mayube -> euabmy
stephens -> nhseespt
aabcdeffghij -> dbfhjfigaeca
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes **in each language** wins!

Comment: `No character is adjacent to a character that it was originally adjacent to`. Does order not matter for adjacency? So input "abcd" cannot have "ab" anywhere, and cannot have "ba" anywhere either?

Comment: @DrZ214 that is correct

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
ẋ2ṡ2Ṣ€
Ç³Ç¤œ&¬ɓ³=Sȯ
ẊÇ¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrm6jhzsXAvGiR01ruA63H9oMxEuOTlY7tObk5EObbYNPrOd6uKsLKLj/////xSWpBRmpecVf8/J1kxOTM1IB)

Extremely long by virtue of my being awful at Jelly, but it finally works, at least... still in the process of golfing.

```
link that generates a list of sorted adjacent pairs:
ẋ2            duplicate argument ("abc" -> "abcabc")
  ṡ2          slices of 2 (-> "ab","bc","ca","ab","bc")
    Ṣ€        sort each

link that tests for invalid permutations:
Ç             get sorted adjacent pairs of argument
 ³Ç¤          do the same for the original input
    œ&        set intersection, then...
      ¬       ...inverse; i.e. do they have no elements in common
       ɓ   ȯ  logical OR the result of that with...
        ³=    elementwise equality with original input, and...
          S   ...sum; i.e. are some characters in the same position

main link:
Ẋ             shuffle the input list
  ¿           while
 Ç            the result of the previous link is truthy
```

Comment: Tested with all testcases in OP, works for all of them

Comment: This might be really long for Jelly, but its extremely short for everything else (with the possible exception of 05AB1E, and a few other insane golfing languages.)

Comment: yeah it's insanely short, I didn't expect even Jelly to do it this golfily, even 05AB1E's **wrong** solution that didn't check original char position was 45 bytes

Comment: There goes another mod, corrupted by Jelly. How sad.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP>=7.1, 147 Bytes

```php
for($a=$argn,$r="^$a[-1].*$a[0]$",$k=0;$v=$a[$k];)$r.="|^.{{$k}}$v|$v".($l=$a[$k++-1])."|$l$v";for(;preg_match("#$r#",$s=str_shuffle($a)););echo$s;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff9639358c96755feecb1e5016fbf58b726a67a6)

## PHP>=7.1, 184 Bytes

Use the levenshtein distance instead of a Regex way

```php
for($a=$argn;$v=$a[$k];$r[]=$l.$v)$r[]=$v.($l=$a[$k++-1]);for(;!$t&&$s=str_shuffle($a);)for($t=1,$i=0;$v=$s[$i];$t*=$v!=$a[$i++])foreach($r as$x)$t*=levenshtein($x,$s[$i-1].$v);echo$s;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/82c1d3d19dd32cbf4eaef6073b13adc428be5285)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 217 bytes

Version under 7.1

```php
for($l=strlen($a=$argn),$r=$a[$k=0].$a[$l-1]."|".$a[$l-1]."$a[0]|^{$a[$l-1]}.*$a[0]$";$v=$a[$k];!$k?:$r.="|$v".$a[$k-1],++$k<$l?$r.="|$v".$a[$k]:0)$r.="|^.{{$k}}$v";for(;preg_match("#$r#",$s=str_shuffle($a)););echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9NboMwEIX3vUWHt8ANscg2jsVBGidCyMSVXWOZNFkAx86amqBKVXbfvB/pTTBhPlTBhDfU8eIlGe26@xeJue1iDif7a3Ta56jlM8AKxESfsLJUfAG33SlOI/07EpVqPA1/ysQ/nhJI4La2lXiHrfaIXNKI29q2KVtsNrAHuOrFUvuSrdKJDwPsNCVLLCNFiPpy/q6vjckpQ8yoQL/sPvfmp22dTuMZE0zoxnToxZwtQEd/9Ijp0Yfvtk3dGP0L)

Comment: ***Oh my god it works***

Comment: Why should it not work? I make every possible regex. If it match shuffle the string till it not match

Comment: wait, fails on `helowi`, outputs `ioewlh`, `i` and `h` are adjacent

Comment: @Mayube Okay that should now make the last case safe

Comment: Yup, tested with all testcases in the OP, they all work

Comment: `++$k<$l` saves 3 bytes. With PHP 7.1, `$l` can be rendered obsolete (if you check `$a[++$k]` instead of `++$k<$l`); that should save 16 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 185 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
x=input()
g=lambda m:set(zip(m*2,(m*2)[1:]))
for l in permutations(x):
 if not((g(l)|g(l[::-1]))&(g(x)|g(x[::-1]))or any(a==b for a,b in zip(x,l))):print`l`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY29CsMgFEZ3n@JOjbekQwJdhDxJCESpSQX/MDdgSt/d6tDlDAe@88WL3sGPpWwpODCkE4VgDzAuhkR3lifj40kc2T5Z6dRLghOHJv4xkbv72DfgPIgFkW0hgQXjIerkTpJkgj94RsHAbOADcb5zi9@KWYjHUDe3anIz@W9qQ/qLy2lS0IKyVy3Z/nJvEVHEZDytdp1HIZ5LKZ2T16l09wM)
Prints all valid strings

Comment: tested for `mayube`, `stephens` and `helowi`, seems to work for all 3. I need to make an output validator to do some more intensive testing though

Comment: Timed out for `aabcdeffghij`, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work, just that it takes longer than a minute for that input

Comment: It takes a LONG time to run "aabcdeffghij" on my machine.  So far >2min.  Also looks like this prints more than one permutation, which is not according to spec.

Comment: Rod - You may save some bytes with `print next(l for l in permutations(x) if not((g(l)|g(l[::-1]))&(g(x)|g(x[::-1]))or any(a==b for a,b in zip(x,l))))`

Comment: @NotthatCharles you forgot the `\`l\`[2::5]` =/

Comment: i can't count...

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 21 bytes

```
p.jP;?z≠ᵐ&j¬{s₂p~s}P∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9icmFjaHlsb2cy//9wLmpQOz964omg4bWQJmrCrHtz4oKCcH5zfVDiiKf//yJhc2RmZ2gi/1o)

### Explanation

I really would have wanted for `p.;?z≠ᵐ&j¬{s₂p~s~j}` to work for 2 bytes less, but it seems `~j` is not smart enough...

```
p.jP;?z≠ᵐ&j¬{s₂p~s}P∧  Input is a string, say ? = "asdfgha"
p                      Take a permutation of ?, say "sfagadh".
 .                     It is the output.
  j                    Concatenate it to itself: "sfagadhsfagadh"
   P                   Call that string P.
    ;?                 Pair P with the input: ["sfagadhsfagadh","asdfgha"]
      z                Zip, repeating elements of the longer string:
                        [["s","a"],["f","s"],["a","d"],...,["a","g"],["d","h"],["h","a"]]
       ≠ᵐ              Each pair must have different elements.
         &             Start new predicate
          j            Concatenate ? to itself: "asdfghaasdfgha"
           ¬{     }    The following cannot be satisfied:
             s₂        Take a substring of length 2
               p       and permute it.
                ~s     It is a substring of
                   P   P.
                    ∧  Do not unify P with the output.
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 7.1, <s>136</s> 131 bytes

inspired by [Jörg´s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125350/55735):

```php
for($a=$argn;$c=$a[$k];)$r.="|$c".($d=$a[$k-1])."|$d$c|^.{".+$k++."}$c";while(preg_match("#$a$r#",($s=str_shuffle($a)).$s));echo$s;
```

Run as pipe with `-r` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88d76bcb156a2ddeb88effca91b04f2958a04eae). (Make sure that PHP version 7.1 or above is selected)

Requires PHP 7.1; add 14 bytes for older PHP: Replace `$k-1` with `($k?:strlen($a))-1`;
(two more bytes for PHP<5.3: `$k?$k-1:strlen($a)-1`)

**breakdown**

```php
# A: loop through input to collect sub-expressions
for($a=$argn;$c=$a[$k];)
    $r.="|$c".($d=$a[$k-1])     # 1. pair of characters
        ."|$d$c"                # 2. reversed pair
        ."|^.{".+$k++."}$c";    # 3. $c is at k-th position
# B: shuffle input until regex does not match the result
while(preg_match("#$a$r#",($s=str_shuffle($a)).$s));    # (input as dummy sub-expression)
# C: print result
echo$s;
```

Comment: @JörgHülsermann a lot more ;)

Comment: @JörgHülsermann The wrapping case is handled in the first iteration (`$c=$a[$k=0], $d=$a[$k-1]`) via `$s.$s`.

Comment: Okay nice trick

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 7.1, <s>187 185 172 178</s> 143 bytes

```php
do for($r=str_shuffle($s=$argn),$p=$i=0;$c=$s[$i];$p+=($c==$z)+preg_match("#$a|$b#",$s.$s))$b=strrev($a=$r[$i-1].$z=$r[$i++]);while($p);echo$r;
```

Run as pipe with `-r` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a136a8d3393176a2361271a3126b9eefadf9959e). (Make sure that PHP version 7.1.0 or above is selected!)

**breakdown**

```php
do
    for($r=str_shuffle($s=$argn),   # 2. shuffle input
        $p=$i=0;$c=$s[$i];          # 3. loop through input
        $p+=($c==$z)                        # 2. set $p if char is at old position
            +preg_match("#$a|$b#",$s.$s)    #    or if adjacency occurs in input
    )
        $b=strrev($a=$r[$i-1].$z=$r[$i++]); # 1. concat current with previous character
while($p);                          # 1. loop until $p is falsy
echo$r;                             # 4. print
```

Comment: Fails on input `mayube`, outputs `yeuamb`, `m` and `a` are adjacent

Comment: Also your online tester doesn't seem to be very good, every testcase I've tried just timesout after 3 seconds

Comment: @Mayube I forgot to mention: Use PHP version 7.1

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>110</s> <s>97</s> 102 bytes

```rb
->s{x=s.chars
t=s*2
x.shuffle!while s.size.times.any?{|i|a,b=(x*2)[i,2];a==s[i]||t[a+b]||t[b+a]}
x*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvPDoIgHADgu09BXixUpvR/jXoQxgEcDDaz5k8XJj52Z9rq9J2@flRTNCyWV5g9A9JY2UMyMMA08QTsaEyrVy/rWo2AgHtrMri7BiK76TYHF2Sh2NpjuuGuoOIiGQPuRAgDl7n6qXIplsTjLFtiXf07mtETGZ5WNd3u9ofj6ZwKtMRP9ygb2Vj9BQ)

Comment: This does not follow the rule of "wrapping" adjacency; for example, I got `3594817062` as an output on your TIO link.

Comment: @Doorknob fixed!

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 6, 116 Bytes

```
f=x=>(h=[...x].sort(_=>Math.random(z=0)-.5)).some(y=>y==x[z]||(x+x).match(y+(q=h[++z]||h[0])+'|'+q+y))?f(x):h.join``
```

```js
f=x=>(h=[...x].sort(_=>Math.random(z=0)-.5)).some(y=>y==x[z]||(x+x).match(y+(q=h[++z]||h[0])+'|'+q+y))?f(x):h.join``

console.log (f('abcdef'));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>23</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
å╘┤‼¬½P¥ë└w↕⌐î◘E{╟u!Ö
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=86d4b413aaab509d89c07712a98c08457bc7752199&i=helowi%0Amayube%0Astephens%0Aaabcdeffghij&a=1&m=2)

Thanks for @recursive for saving 2 bytes.

Takes a very long time to run. A more reasonable/feasible version is (just 2 bytes longer)

```
Ç≡╨áiS║çdèû.#-Gî☺└╨◙σφ+
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80f0d0a06953ba87648a962e232d478c01c0d00ae5ed2b&i=helowi%0Amayube%0Astephens%0Aaabcdeffghij&a=1&m=2)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
w|Nc_:=nGyG|*{E-!f+}ch+2B
w                            Loop anything before `}` while
 |N                          Next permutation (starting from the input)
   c_:=                      Index where the current array has the same element as the input (*)
                   }ch+2B    Define a block that finds all contiguous pairs in current string, including the pair `[last element, first element]`
       nG                    Apply the defined block to current string                         
         yG                  Do the same for the input
           |*                Outer product, contains pairs (which themselves are pairs) constructed from the last two array.
             {   f           Only keep pairs
              E-!            whose two elements have the same set of characters
                  +          Prepend the array at step (*).
                             This is used as the condition for the while loop
```

Comment: Nice.  There's an improvement you can make using `G`.  You are doing `{...}X!...x!` to execute the same block twice.  In general, you can rewrite this as `G...G `  with  `}...`  at the end of the program, like [this](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=w%7CNc_%3A%3DnGyG%7C*%7BE-%21f%2B%7Dch%2B2B&i=helowi%0Amayube%0Astephens%0Aaabcdeffghij&a=1&m=2).

Comment: Thank you. I have seen you used `G` in another post to save one byte by replacing `{...}*` with `D...`. I guess am just still not quite used to it ...